# Problem Loading Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I signed up for a Google Maps API key and the documentation I got after doing so says to load the Javascript Maps API, use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=[My API Key]"></script>
```

In using that code snippet I can't get the [Google Maps Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html) working so I changed the script tag above to match the one in the tutorial:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

And that one seems to work fine and doesn't have a reference to my API key... if that works fine is there any reason to get and use the API key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember, the V3 API doesn't require an API Key anymore *(it was required with V2 of the API)*.

In your first code sample, you are using API v2.

But, in your second portion of code, you don't specify an API version -- in this case, I suppose it uses the default version, which currently is v3.

Comment: Martin: That explains it... I am intending to use the v3 API so I guess signing up for the API key wasn't necessary. Thanks!